# Como pegar apenas 1 item dentro de um array, JSON & PHP

Tags: php, json, api, google-drive-api

Estou aprendendo um pouco de json e php, consegui exibir os valores com a api do saveoffline.com

```
https://www.saveoffline.com/process/?url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S1mpK5wti6CEOeJSxJXcDphwWzwxEM7Y/view&type=json
```

nesse link ele me retorna:

```
{"title":"big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4","thumbnail":"https:\/\/lh5.googleusercontent.com\/KKqP0AeJV1nJ_hMFCoNCZT0O8ChZo1L_D7jFDW3NH3cleq8Af1gTt1cIDXE=w1200-h630-p","urls":[{"id":"https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=9vry62JUyxM3dzmf0D9I90HlqKwN5g6S","label":"720p
- mp4","size":"x"},{"id":"https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=GQe6sGKPBeZ0t7llfv3tkWnbdfLLFGiU","label":"480p
- mp4","size":"x"},{"id":"https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=y5GcR5x21bLP7oqHebuniMyFygopsZIB","label":"360p
- mp4","size":"x"}]}
```

consegui exibir os links etc. com foreach, como faço para pegar o link da ultima linha que contem **360p - mp4**

```
{"id":"https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=y5GcR5x21bLP7oqHebuniMyFygopsZIB","label":"360p
    - mp4","size":"x"}]}
```

gostaria de usar esse link para redirecionar para o link raiz do video.

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa selecionar o índice do item que você quer. Primeiro crie uma variável pra manipular esse JSON, se já tem feito isso, ignore.

```
$jsonS = json_decode($json_text);
```

Vou usar seu JSON como exemplo.

```
"result":
[{
"id":"https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=y5GcR5x21bLP7oqHebuniMyFygopsZIB",
"label":"360p - mp4",
"size":"x"
}]
```

Nesse retorno se só quiser o link faça o seguinte:

```
echo "Link " . $jsonS->results[0]->id;
```

Como resposta, setá exibido o seguinte:

```
Link https:\/\/www.saveoffline.com\/get\/?i=Ta4u04ottJ1pNuuBI0b825pX6NPCR7lo&u=y5GcR5x21bLP7oqHebuniMyFygopsZIB
```

Comment: no caso so quero o link da 3 opção aonde se encontra a qualidade "360p - MP4", mas temo que cada video podera ter mais de 4 opções

Comment: consegui pegar aqui, no caso esta na $json->urls[2]->id
posição 2

Comment: Otimo! o caminho é esse mesmo, entre os colchetes você coloca o índice o objeto que quer pegar